# Dropdown doesn't fill with values from variable

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have got 2 dropdown list and 2 variables: ***DropdownSection***, ***DropdownEmployee***.
***DropdownSection*** is filled with values from variable ***SectionWithBlank*** which is from SP List. My ***OnVisible*** action:
`ClearCollect(SectionWithBlank,{Title:""}); Collect(SectionWithBlank,Distinct(ops_tc2_wydzialy, Title))`

That works corretly. Now I fill my ***EmployeeWithBlank*** variable with values depending on value selected in ***DropdownSection***. My ***OnChange*** event in ***DropdownSection***: `ClearCollect(EmployeeWithBlank, {Title:""}); Collect(EmployeeWithBlank, Distinct(Filter(ops_tc2_pracownicy_1, wydzial=Dropdown1.Selected.Value), imie & " " & nazwisko))`.

When i pick something in **DropdownSection**, my **DropdownEmployee** contains only empty values (e.g. when i got 5 values in my variable (**EmployeeWithBlank**), my **DropdownEmployee** got 5 empty values). When i go to *View* -> *Collections*, my **EmployeeWithBlank** variable contains correct values (not empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your DropdownEmployee control is not properly bound to the EmployeeWithBlank collection, or is displaying a different field in that table which has blank values.

To check, select the dropdown. Choose **"Advanced"** in the property pane on the right, and under the Data section make sure:
1. The Items are set to EmployeeWithBlank
2. The correct column name for what you want to display in the dropdown is selected in **Values** [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx62g.png)

Comment: You led me to the correct solution, in my dropdown Value was set to "Title" instead of "Result", i changed it to "Result" and everything works fine.